# Display a page's elements as selectable (HTML/PHP)

Tags: php, html, selectable

I am looking for a way to make all visible objects in a webpage selectable by a visitor.

For example, I take google's homepage as source, my php script already gets the homepage, and stores everything in an array.

Now I want to show the google homepage with **every object** (span, div, body, td etc...) **selectable**. 
My visitor will select a few objects and then click submit (form post)

I do not know how to do this, even after searching dhtml and so ..

Thansk for your help

Mykeul

Answer (score 1):

1. Parse the html page, if the actual element has an ID, just store, if not set an ID.
2. When you have all ID-s set a border for each element
3. Set an onClick, onMouseOver event handler
4. Handle clicking
5. Finally post the select element's id

Jquery would help you.

Comment: Hello,
I worked on your proposal, JQuery helped me. I succeeded to set the border but I dont know how to:
- highlight elements with CSS on mouseover. Is there a way to set a foreground color with 50% opacity for example ?
- handle clicking
Do you have some examples/howtos to help me ?

Thanks,
Mykeul